# megacli64.exe manual

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, megaraid, megacli

Is there any document that explains the command line switches of *megacli* better than the cryptic output of `megacli64 -h` ?

The machine is an IBM x3650 m3 to which I added three more disks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called the [MegaRAID SAS Software User Guide](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/MegaRAID%20Common%20Files/SASUG_51530-00_RevH.pdf) (beware, link may load very slowly). See Chapter 5, MegaRAID Command Tool.